# Change file name while uploading using Zend_From

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form, zend-form-element

I want to change uploading file name. Below is the code I have written:

```
 $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
 $upload->setDestination(IMAGE_PHY_PATH);
 try { 
    //upload received file(s)
    $upload->addFilter('Rename', array('target'    => IMAGE_PHY_PATH."1.jpg",
                                       'overwrite' => true));
    $upload->receive();
 } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What *is* wrong with your code? Errors? What does it do?

Comment: it uploads file but it doesnot rename the file. in my case I have written static name that is "1.jpg" for testing. but it does not change file name to defined file name :(

Comment: What is the value of `IMAGE_PHY_PATH`?

Comment: This question is too vague to answer, please provide more information.  In what way does the above code not work?

Comment: @ GordonM :I actually wants to upload file but before uploading, I want to rename the file. what else specification you want for the problem?

Comment: @mahok : I have defined the constant . it is the path where my file will be uploaded .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rename = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
    'target'    => IMAGE_PHY_PATH . '1.jpg',
    'overwrite' => true
));

$upload->addFilter($rename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `realpath(IMAGE_PHY_PATH)`. This should produce an absolute pathname (ex: `$adapter->setDestination('C:\temp')`).

After this check to see if the path exists and is writable. Normally setDestination should throw an exception if not so. If the path is correct call $form->getValues() after the try/catch block.